# Tagged Packets on native VLAN General Port

Tags: switch, vlan, trunk

Scenario a)

I have a Switchport (g1) in General-Mode. Say g1 is member of VLAN1 (native, untagged) and VLAN2 (tagged).
Another Port (g2) is in Trunk-Mode, and member of VLAN1 and VLAN2

If i send a packet, tagged with VLAN1 over g2, is this packet leaving port g1 tagged (with VLAN1) or untagged (because native VLAN1) ?

Scenario b)

I have a Switchport (g1) in General-Mode. Say g1 is member of VLAN1 (native, untagged) and VLAN2 (tagged).
Another Port (g2) is also in general mode and member of VLAN1 (native, untagged) and VLAN2

If i send a packet, tagged (before entering the switch) with VLAN1 over g2, is this packet leaving port g1 tagged (with VLAN1) or untagged (because native VLAN1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario a)  It leaves g1 untagged.

Scenario b)  Again, untagged.

The switch will strip the VLAN tags when packets leave on an untagged interface.

Comment: So there is no "mix-mode" (Stripping only the Tags of the Native-VLAN and leaving the Tags on non-Native VLANs)?

Comment: @int2000 in both cases, packets were leaving a port on it's native vlan.  If you were sending packets on VLAN2, they would leave with VLAN tags.